# getaddrinfo(): how to distinguish between resolution failure and non-resolvable hostname?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, dns

In theory, the return value from `getaddrinfo(3)` should allow to distinguish between a hostname that cannot be resolved, and a problem with the DNS server:

```
RETURN VALUE
       getaddrinfo()  returns  0  if  it  succeeds,  or  one of the following
       nonzero error codes:

       EAI_ADDRFAMILY
              The specified network host does not have any network  addresses
              in the requested address family.

       EAI_AGAIN
              The  name  server returned a temporary failure indication.  Try
              again later.

       EAI_NODATA
              The  specified  network host exists, but does not have any net-
              work addresses defined.
```

(extract from `man 3 getaddrinfo`).

In practice, there seems to be little difference though:

```
$ ./getaddr_test www.google.invalid 80
getaddrinfo returned -2 (Name or service not known), errno is errno: 2
$ sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf # point to non-existing nameserver
$ ./getaddr_test www.google.com 80
getaddrinfo returned -2 (Name or service not known), errno is errno: 2
$ ./getaddr_test www.google.invalid 80
getaddrinfo returned -2 (Name or service not known), errno is errno: 2
$ uname -o -v
#1 SMP Debian 3.14.12-1 (2014-07-11) GNU/Linux
```

Is there any other way to distinguish an unresolvable hostname from an unreachable DNS server (that does not require me to perform a second lookup for a "known-good" hostname)?

Here's the source of the test program that I used:

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *result;
  int ret;

  if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s host port...\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; /* Stream socket */
  hints.ai_protocol = 0;          /* Any protocol */
  hints.ai_flags = 0;

  ret = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &result);
  if (ret != 0) 
    printf("getaddrinfo returned %d (%s), errno is errno: %d\n",
           ret, gai_strerror(ret), errno);
  else
    printf("getaddrinfo succeeded.");
}
```

Comment: After looking through netdb.h, I've found that the return value of -2 is equal to EAI_NONAME.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why its not distinguishing this is that it has more than one source of information for resolving a name.  Most Linuxes use NSS to aggregate those sources and by default use /etc/hosts file based resolution as well as DNS resolution (but possibly LDAP and others).

You could try your test again with your nsswitch.conf file having 'hosts' set to 'dns' only but that solution if it even worked wouldn't be terribly reliable.

The only complete solution I can imagine that would give you full control over this would be contacting the DNS servers yourself.  If you can't open a socket to them then you know they can't be reached.  If you can but a name doesn't resolve you know its an invalid name.